# Outlook 2019 pdf Previewer - How to specify CutePDF - NOT Adobe Reader

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf

I have uninstalled Adobe Reader and Acrobat in favour of CutePDF.  Consequently, I have no Outlook Previewer.  I want to specify CutePDF as the Outlook Previewer.  How can this be done please?  Presumably some registry edits are required . . .  OS is Win10 v20H2

Answer (score 0):

Not know much about ***CutePDF***, but if you had issues about PDF Preview Handler in Outlook, the steps in ***[this TechNet Articles](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53322.outlook-problem-with-pdf-preview-handler.aspx)*** should be able to bring you some inspiration. And for specific settings about CutePDF, have you ever tried to contact the support of CutePDF?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but that article relates to Adobe Reader.
Yes, Cute Tech Support was not helpful :-(     Which is why I am here !

Comment: What I can found from my tests is that the CutePDF will not be detected by Outlook in the Preview Handler list. And the CutePDF seems only open files via web browser instead of "independent program", which is different from what Adobe Reader behaves. Can this become the cause of this issue? I'm not a CutePDF user, if I told something wrong about it, please kindly forgive me about that.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Jeff.  You have come to the same conclusion as me!  Therefore, I have decided not to pursue this further.

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, in order to close this thread normally, it would be so nice of you to kindly marking helpful reply as answers. Warm regards!